# Can a signed apk be illegal?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk

I'm currently creating an app with Android Studio.
I was curious on how I could create an apk and release it on the Google Play, for example.

I saw that there was various informations to give in to be able to create an apk, and that there were keys to create.

So, my question is: Is it possible to create an apk that would be considered as illegal, because of the informations I gave?
Should I be aware of some consequences to create an app as a single person and not a company?

Comment: **Yes**, it can. Imagine an app which contains injuries to a person (or more). Or one which promotes racism or any form of discrimination. Or one that teaches how to build a bomb by using household items. Or simply an app which steals your money (or just  your private data). I guess these examples answer your question. Not even to mention the usage of copyrighted material.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein No, I was talking about the informations I give when creating the apk. Of course, the elements you listed are a problem, but I wanted to know if the informations given when creating the apk could be a problem. Like, can a keystore that I created considered illegal? Or having a pseudo and not my real name?

Comment: I don't think this kind of info is considered not valid. An alias is like a company name. It always refers to you, as a registered developer. Other is if you declare that your app doesn't use in-app purchases, but in facts it does.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Okay, thank you very much. Can you make an answer, so I can close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, it can.

Imagine an app which contains injuries to a person (or more).
Or one which promotes racism or any form of discrimination.
Or one that teaches how to build a bomb by using household items.
Or simply an app which steals your money (or just your private data).

Not even to mention the usage of copyrighted material.

I guess these examples answer your question.

> can a keystore that I created considered illegal?
>     Or having a pseudo
>   and not my real name?

I don't think this kind of info is considered not valid.
An alias is like a company name. It always refers to you, as a registered developer.

Other is if you declare that your app doesn't use in-app purchases, but in facts it does.